# How to add image using builder.addaction(icon,"string",pendingIntent) method of notification in android?

Tags: android, notifications, drawable

I have built a notification and I am trying to show a desired icon using:

```
builder.addAction(R.drawable.image_id,"text",pendingIntent);
```

but it shows only a grey color box instead of image.And on the other side if I write as:

```
builder.addAction(android.R.drawable.btn_star_big_on, " text", pendingIntent);
```

It shows icon(star:grey color) that is inbuilt in android I think.
 So is there any way to print the desired icon in notification area ?

Comment: Do you want the action to show your icon or do you want to show your icon in the notification bar?

Comment: I want to show Icon with the action name like in gmail notification there are  two icon i.e. one for ARCHIVE and 2nd one for REPLY.

Comment: Are you sure that you have added the image in res->drawable-hdpi folder??

Comment: yes I have defined it :F:\App\Emp\app\src\main\res\drawable-hdpi\appr.png.

Comment: Please check the size of your icon - it may be that your drawable is way to big - or too small. 
Because of your last comment: you replaced image_id with appr - right?

Comment: @Ritz Have you solve your problem ? I also have same problem...

Comment: This issue is only with marshmallow OS. In this they changes the notification addAction() method

Comment: Hey Sachin I solved it....... in my case there was icon size mismatch.we can add any icon in notification but condition is its size should be according to notification icon size standards. hope this will help you.

Comment: @Ritz What are **notification icon size standards**?

Answer (score 1):

You can try to get the id of your image with the following way and then pass it in your Notification Builder

```
String mDrawableName = "btn_star_big_on";

int resID = getResources().getIdentifier(mDrawableName , "drawable", getPackageName());

builder.addAction(resID,"text",pendingIntent);
```

Try that.

Comment: Thanks for reply, I tried it but same problem,not solved.

Comment: check have you imported android.R; if yes remove it and then try